# Is this mysql thread-safe?

Tags: mysql, concurrency, transactions

I have a table with following columns : `id(int), wallet_id (int), amount (int), recharge_date (timestamp), status (int)`. `status` represents pending(0), success(1) or failed(2). I need to make sure before recharging that total amount recharged for current month doesn't exceed 10,000. I also need to cover scenarios with 2 or more simultaneous requests for recharging.

I am thinking following steps could help avoid race-conditions:

1. Insert into table with status 0 (pending) for a wallet_id say "1234"
2. Select sum(amount) from table where wallet_id = 1234 AND month(recharge_date) = current month and status in (0,1)
3. If this sum is more than 10,000 then update status to 2(failed) and return.
4. Do some application level operations and then update status to either 1(success) or 2(failed)

Do these steps ensure thread-safety ? Also, is there any other simpler way in mysql of ensuring thread-safety for this use case ?

Edit: 
Explaining Actual flow for more clarity:

1. Server receives request to add amount of 500 for a certain wallet_id(say 99).
2. Insert a new order in pending status: INSERT INTO orders VALUES (wallet_id = 99, amount = 500, status = pending)
3. Need to make sure you can do atmost 10,000 amount recharge in a month. So SELECT SUM(amount) WHERE wallet_id = 99 AND month=current_month AND status IN(pending, success)
4. If sum in step 3 is >= 10,000 then update status of order created in step 2 to failed. Return
5. If sum is < 10,000 then do some other stuff, come back and update order created in step 2 to success or failed.

Confusion arises if more than one simultaneous request is received for this flow.

Answer (score 1):

Good catch on the concurrency thing. [Database transactions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/commit.html) are made for this.

You can do this with such a transaction. (not debugged)

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

SELECT SUM(amount) INTO @sum
  FROM mytable
 WHERE status IN (0,1)
   AND recharge_date >= LAST_DAY(CURDATE()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 1 MONTH
   AND recharge_date < LAST_DAY(CURDATE()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY 
   AND wallet_id = (((whatever))
   FOR update;

UPDATE mytable SET status=2
 WHERE status IN (0,1)
   AND recharge_date >= LAST_DAY(CURDATE()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 1 MONTH
   AND recharge_date < LAST_DAY(CURDATE()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY 
   AND wallet_id = (((whatever))
   AND @sum > 1000;

/* then do your application logic, and come back and do */

UPDATE mytable SET status=(((whatever)))
 WHERE status IN (0,1)
   AND recharge_date >= LAST_DAY(CURDATE()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 1 MONTH
   AND recharge_date < LAST_DAY(CURDATE()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY 
   AND wallet_id = (((whatever))
   AND @sum > 1000;

/* finally, commit your transaction. */
COMMIT;
```

Notice how the `SELECT...FOR UPDATE` and the two `UPDATE` statements all have the same `WHERE` statement.  That's important because you must avoid updating rows you didn't select for update.  When you're done, `COMMIT` the transaction. If you decide you don't want to proceed at any time after the `BEGIN TRANSACTION` you can `ROLLBACK` the transaction and things return to the state they were in before you began.

This pattern

```
   AND recharge_date >= LAST_DAY(CURDATE()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 1 MONTH
   AND recharge_date < LAST_DAY(CURDATE()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

is the best way to choose dates in the present calendar month. It allows the use of an index on the column to search for relevant records, where `MONTH(recharge_date) = MONTH(CURDATE())` doesn't.

I'm a bit confused about one thing. You said you need to do a SUM, which indicates that multiple records in your table are affected by your intended `status` change. Is that truly what you want?

Comment: Edited for more clarity on your last question. Info on using index over "recharge_date" was great to know.